# Is there a way to refresh a fragment in the onResume method?

Tags: kotlin, android-fragments, onresume, fragment-oncreateview

My favourites fragment does not display the data given correctly unless the onCreateView function is called. This means that the fragment needs to be deleted and created again. Is there a way to appropriately refresh the fragment in the onResume method?

```
override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val fragment = this

        _binding = FragmentFavouritesBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        binding.recyclerView.apply{
            layoutManager = GridLayoutManager(activity,2)
            adapter= CardAdapter(favouriteList, fragment)
        }
        return binding.root
    }
```

```
override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()

        orderFavourites()
        sortFavourites()
        
        if(favouriteList.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this.context,"No Favourites Found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        else{
            Toast.makeText(this.context,"resumed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
```

The favouriteList is updated in another activity and I have ensured that it contains the correct values. It displays as intended after deleting and creating the fragment once more.

Comment: how are you updating `favouriteList` from the activity?

Comment: You can just extract the code where you set the adapter into it's own method and call that manually when you need to "refresh" your data.

Comment: @Praveen favouriteList is a mutable list inside a kotlin class I created. I simply add objects to that list and I know it holds the correct values as intended currently.

Comment: @Robin I don't quite understand what you mean? I have attempted to use the same code that's in the onCreateView inside the onResume and that doesn't appear to work.